# How can I deal with variable amounts of data in $_REQUEST?

Tags: java, php, http

Let me start this off by saying I don't really know PHP... I am fiddling my way around it for a project.

I am POSTing data from a Java program to my .php file. My current issue is that now I want my Java function to post data to the PHP file, but it won't always be there. For example, sometimes I'll want to send these pairs:

```
 (fruit1, apple)
 (fruit2, orange)
 (fruit3, banana)
```

And sometimes I'll want to send just

```
 (fruit1, apple)  
 (fruit2, orange)
```

How can I intelligently use `$_REQUEST` to know if the data is there or not? If when I do `$_REQUEST['fruit3']` and there's nothing there, like in the last case, what happens? Is that a `null`? Would `if ($_REQUEST['fruit3'])` evaluate to false in this case?

I'd obviously like to ultimately do something like this: (this is kind of pseudo code)

```
 for ($i=0; $i < totalFruits; $i++)
 {
       processFruit($_REQUEST[fruit + 'i']);
 }
```

I'd appreciate any help to do this the clean/proper way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop over each variable in the request and check that it starts with fruit. Use strict === conditional since you are checking for the start position in the string and not false.

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $val) {
    // make sure fruit is at the beginning of the string, but not false
    if (strpos($key, 'fruit')===0) { 
        processFruit($val);
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $val)` seems to be the missing magic I didn't know existed. So this puts the POST key value pairs in `$key` and `$value` for each iteration of the loop, and I can just google my way through string logic from there?

Comment: Correct, of course swap $_POST for $_REQUEST if you want post variables. The strpos logic will handle the check for "fruit".

Comment: In my actual implementation for certain reasons I actually had to have it be "1fruit", "2fruit", "3fruit".... all that changes is `if (strpos($key, 'fruit')===1)` correct? I'm going to mark this as an accepted answer once I get it working... I'm pretty close now.

Comment: In that case can get by with `if (strpos($key, 'fruit') !== false)`

Comment: Sorry, I left out some details in order to try to make the question concise. There will ALWAYS be `$key` data present that is `fruit`. Just sometimes theres more keys called '1fruit', '2fruit', '3fruit', etc. So I want to make sure that I'm getting a `xfruit` and not the normal `fruit` that's always there. Does that make sense? So I do need to do `if (strpos($key, 'fruit')===1)` right?